# jQuery simple load taking too much time for first call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, https, load

My Simple jQuery's load statement taking too much time (50+ seconds). There is no server side issue and server's page logic is simple. I also have tried **$.ajax**, **$.get** and even tried using Manual AJAX call **(XMLHttpRequest)**.

Following is the example with jQuery load.

```
$(function() {
    $('#frmPrd').live('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mUrl = "page1.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: mUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#frmPrd").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                //Logged Unix timestamp here which was 1448631101 (27 Nov 2015 13:31:41 GMT)
                $("#dvCart").load("page.php");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occurred.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And then in **page.php** I logged (very first statement of page) timestamp which returned 1448631153 (27 Nov 2015 13:32:33 GMT) i.e. 52 seconds difference from the timestamp I logged before calling the page.
What can be the issue here? Where are these 50+ seconds wasted?
Also note that this delay is for first call, for all coming calls the delay is normal. My whole website runs on https (TLS 1.2)

Comment: and what does page1.php do?

Comment: In FireFox (other browsers have similar options) - F12, select Network, reload your page.  Look at where the timings are.   Start-Finish might be 52s, but it could be 50s just for 'Connecting'

Comment: @Wolfeh pag1.php adds item into cart. frmPrd is having the item data which is to be added in cart

Comment: @freedomn-m its the GET request to page.php which is showing around 52 seconds in Network (Firefox). But the page is not hit in first 51 seconds as per the time logging.

Comment: Note that this huge amount of time is only for first time (i.e. first item being added in cart), for all other calls this process in completed under 1 second or maximum takes a second which is normal and as per expectations.

Comment: 51 seconds in **Timings** section of Network (Firefox). Waiting for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was initial handshake with https server which was taking time.