# First AJAX call taking too much time in wait

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response, wait

My first AJAX request (manual or using jQuery's load, get, post, ajax) takes too much time (50+ seconds). Following AJAX requests becomes normal.

When I troubleshoot the problem using Network section of Chrome and Firefox it showed that it takes almost 51 seconds in waiting (attached is the screenshot). Why is this taking so much time? I am clueless that for which thing the request is waiting for.
Here is my code

```
$(function() {
    $('#frmPrd').live('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mUrl = "page1.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: mUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#frmPrd").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                //Following request is taking 50+ seconds.
                $("#dvCart").load("page.php");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occurred.');
            }  
        });
    });
});
```

The screeshot of Network section
[image: Waiting for what?]

I already have asked the question (following link) but still the issue is not solved.
[jQuery simple load taking too much time for first call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958840/jquery-simple-load-taking-too-much-time-for-first-call)

Comment: This seems more like a server issue. What's the code doing in your `page1.php` file? Also `live()` was deprecated and remove from jQuery a *long* time ago. I would strongly suggest you update the version you're using, and change the method call to the delegated signature of the `on()` method.

Comment: Page1.php is adding item to cart (Session is used as well) while page.php are the Cart contents which I am updating on any item being added in cart. I also thought of Session lock issue and tried using **session_write_close()** but that didn't worked either.

Comment: I would possibly also contact your hosting provider. I can almost guarantee you this is not a JS issue.

Comment: Yes its not a JS issue, its my guess too. But where are these 51 seconds going. I am clueless. And this happens for first Ajax call only.

Comment: I think $("#dvCart").load("page.php"); is takes more time ,, check page.php

Comment: page.php takes no time. I logged the time on very first statement and then at very last statement. It was in no time almost. Also the logic of page.php is very simple. Moreover the screenshot I attached shows that its not the page.php but its the waiting time.

Comment: Why the question is down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wait time depends entirely upon your server (and in some cases on your network connection).  This is the time from when the request was sent by the client until it first starts receiving the response.  Assuming you're not on a really slow network connection or one with really bad latency (like a satellite link), this is pretty much all about how long it takes the server to respond to the request.

If only the very first ajax call is this slow, then there is probably some sort of "startup" time on the server.  If this is a busy server or overloaded server, then it could be that your app is swapped out of memory or the cache is empty and it takes a longer time to get your app up and running and ready to start processing the response.  This might be more common in a shared hosting environment when there are many other active applications sharing the same resources and your server has not been recently active.

Since this looks like a PHP server, it could be that the PHP engine used by the web server has some startup time or the web server has to load something before it can start processing PHP requests and that initialization takes a bunch of time.  Or, it could be as simple as a hard drive on the server had been powered down and it has to spin up to speed before things can start processing.

It will take instrumenting and profiling on the server to find out exactly which possible issue is the main cause of the server-side delay.

Comment: Its not a network issue. I have checked on multiple machines and many of my customers (from different regions) are complaining the same thing. Moreover its a cloud server and server is not at all a busy one. I mean traffic is not very much. Can this be a https handshake issue? or may be the Session lock issue?

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam - that sounds right because subsquent requests are fine so it must be some sort of "startup" issue on the server for the first request.

Comment: Its not a network issue. I have checked on multiple machines and many of my customers (from different regions) are complaining the same thing. Moreover its a cloud server and server is not at all a busy one. I mean traffic is not very much. Can this be a https handshake issue? or may be the Session lock issue?
- - 
How should I troubleshoot for the startup issue?

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam - SSL could also be part of the delay.  If I recall, some SSL credentials can be cached from one connection to the next, but the first time credentials are created, it can take longer.  I wouldn't think that would explain 50 seconds, but it could contribute.

Comment: Any more suggestions to troubleshoot the issue? I mean to trace out where these 51 seconds are being used?

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam - Is it a dedicated or shared cloud server?  What you need to figure out is what is the server doing during that 50 seconds.  That's such a long time that you can probably actually observe some things in real time such as networking activity, disk activity, CPU usage, etc...  You may also want to instrument/log some things in your web server to determine where it thinks the time is being spent.  The details of how to do this depends entirely upon your configuration (OS, web server, etc...) which you have told us nothing about.

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam - And, the process is typically one of observing a number of factors to see what the info tells you, looking for leads or things that don't look normal, investigating those leads to see what you learn from them, following that thread to see what you can learn, instrumenting things relevant to your lead, etc....

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam - Are you using any external resources such as a database that might have initialization time?  Are there any types of locks on resources that you might be stuck waiting for a timeout on?

Comment: Its a dedicated Cloud Server. In page1.php I have used database as well as the session. DB is already connected using PDO so this should not be the issue but I think Session locking is the issue I am facing (not sure though) but will try to troubleshoot according to your instructions.
Server information [link](http://i.imgur.com/qBlYKxU.jpg)